# Achartengine cannot resolve symbol setLineWidth

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am trying to create the `renderer` in `achartengine` but `Android` gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol setLineWidth
```

I seem to be doing everything right as here is my code:

```
private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setLineWidth(2);
```

Here are my imports:

```
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop around all renderers in an `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, use this:

```
int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer
                    .getSeriesRendererAt(i);                
            seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        }
```